# Priority rules for abridging Selichot

Tags: selichot, synagogue, tefilla

If the minyan doesn't have enough time allotted for Selichot to finish everything listed in the Selichot book for today, so you need to cut some parts out, what are the rules of priority for what should be cut out first, last, or never?

Comment: Isaac, I have seen abridged versions under the theory of "tov me'at b'chavanah" (can anyone verify if they do this in Chaim Berlin?), but why can't the minyan just start earlier?

Comment: Not every shul can scrape together enough people who are willing to devote two hours to shul every morning for a week or more.

Answer (score 3):

The least I've seen is Ashrei, kaddish, (don't remember about the pesukim), s'lach lanu-intro to 13 midos-13 midos until lechol korecha, pizmon, intro+13 midos, the rest like a regular fast day (including only one ashamnu), niphilas apaim, shomer...

Answer (score 2):

There are the many things that are simply Yeish Nohagim, that could be (and often are) skipped.  There is also the final Keil Melekh and Hashem HaShem that according to Kabbalah and Minhag Beit El don't belong there.

However, really a competent posek should be consulted.